# What will happen after formating (LUKS) encrypted partition with sensitive data?

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I would like to better understand what will happen to encrypted data after formating encrypted partition.For instance i have USB disk with some sensitive data in encrypted partition.My view is that now are data only random bytes on flash and after formating it will be still unrecoverable without passphrase.It is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the password, the data is just random bits. Its only possible to make meaning of the data when you have the password. You can consider the drive securely erased if you "forget" the password. Editing the partition tables has no security effect; the encrypted data is still there.

Secure erase on encrypted disks is accomplished primarily by this same method. By destroying the disk encryption key, all of the data on the disk becomes permanently unreadable. Only for performance reasons will a zeroing out of the drive occur.